# Generate A Timestamp As Universal Reference Point

Tags: java, android, firebase, epoch

I am creating a firebase application that is going to utilize some sort of timestamp to serve as a child. I want to ensure that this timestamp accounts for all time zones and that it can be used as a reference point moving forward. I know there is the concept of an epoch unit, but I am not too familiar with epoch.

For instance, if I create a timestamp of 1 from the US, I want somebody else to create a timestamp that is x number of units from the US timestamp, meaning if he creates it a minute later, his timestamp is 61. So far, I have created the following:

```
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   final String epochTime = String.valueOf(c.getTimeInMillis());                             
   mBaseRef.child("Polls").child(epochTime).child("Question").setValue(mCreatePollQuestion.getText().toString());
```

Here is how I envision it in Firebase:

[image]

Let me know if I have the right idea!

Comment: In epoch, `0` is January 1, 1970 at midnight UTC.

Comment: Got it, so am I creating an epoch through my method above?

Comment: [`Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis--) ***Returns:** the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.*

Comment: Got it, so I guess my next question is how to account for the time zone difference. In other words, if I want somebody in Europe who generates the epoch to ensure that it is one second accounted for after my reference time, does this method do that? Or do I need to add some time zone considerations to the calendar?

Comment: UTC is like a timezone. In fact, UTC is a *universal reference point*.

Comment: With the Firebase Database, you'll want to look at using a [server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps). This is the type of value you're looking for, but then generated server-side.